# Passing both objects into each other?

Tags: python

How can I pass both objects in each other?

For example:

```
player = Player(obstacle)
obstacle = Obstacle(player)
```

If I do this it will say

`Unresolved reference "obstacle"`

And I do understand why, but is it still possible to pass `obstacle` in `player`?

Comment: You need to know more about the types to do that. Just given a function that takes an obstacle and returns a player and a function that takes a player and returns an obstacle and nothing else, it’s impossible to create either – but maybe you can create one first and associate them after they’re both created if the classes allow for it.

Comment: Could you give more context. There's probably another way.

Comment: @MSeifert and Ryan are right. More context is needed. _Why_ does `Player()` need a reference to an obstacle and _why_ does `Obstacle()` need a reference to a player? Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/helpa/mcve) which demonstrates your _entire_ problem?

Comment: This sounds like you should have a third class that inherits from the abstract classes player and obstacle, which don't inherit from eachother

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass `obstacle` to `player` because at the beginning there are no `obstacle`s. You should create an empty `player`, create an `obstacle` and assign the `obstacle` to the `player`:

```
player = Player()
obstacle = Obstacle(player)
player.obstacle = obstacle
```

Please note this creates a reference loop which is a problematic for garbage collector to cleanup. Consider using [weak references](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) to create mutually referencing objects.